# Detect an element resize, but not right away

Tags: javascript, resize, greasemonkey

I have a userscript that detects if a certain bar fills up more, except there is one problem: on the load of the page, instead of just showing the current % and then going up later when x action occurs, it starts at 0 every page load, then animates up to the current %, and then goes up when x action occurs.

How can I get around this? I've tried `@run-at document-idle` and `$("#meterFill").finish()` at the beginning of my script but neither seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
new ResizeSensor($("#meterFill"), function () {
        console.log("do something");
    });
```

Comment: Post an MCVE.  But  you probably just need to run the function separately, once, when the script first runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem adding `jQuery.fx.off = true` to the start of my script.